# Github mirroring: How can I set default branch when pushing

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am following this https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository to migrate repositories from Gitlab to Github (enterprise).

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
cd old-repository.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

The steps are packaged in a script that I run once per week.

I noticed that the default branch on GitHub is set to a random branch, rather to the default branch defined in git and gitlab.

Let's say I have a repo `X`, with 4 branches:

> master  (default branch)
> dev
> feature-1
> feature-2

When I run the script the first time for a new repository, the default branch on GitHub is set to a `feature-1`.
Then in the meantime, developers merge the `feature-1` in `dev`, and delete it.
Next time I run the script, it will try to delete `feature-1` branch on Github, as it is in gitlab, and fail with an error:

> '![remote rejected] feature-1234 (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/feature-1234)

I tried `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master` before pushing, but still no success.

I know I can change default branch setting with github API after pushing, but I want to avoid doing this.

Any idea how I can archive this?

**EDIT**:
Avoiding Github API because of proxy restriction from where the script is running.

Comment: The default branch *on the server* is (must be) set *on the server*. The `HEAD` setting in any client is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: "I can change default branch setting with github API after pushing, but I want to avoid doing this." Then the alternative is to use the GitHub web interface in your browser. It's easy and simple. — Of course you could use the `gh` command line tool.  https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_edit But under the hood that's the GitHub API to which you mysteriously object.

Comment: @torek thank you for this information. I was not aware of that.

Comment: @matt changing in web interface is not an option since I am synching hundreds of repositories.
I though there was a way to do this in git repo client side before pushing, but it seems not possible. Therefore, I am thinking on doing it with gitlab API.  
BTW I was avoiding GitHub API because of proxy restriction where I am running this script. Therefore I'll have to use the API from another network.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to @torek, It seems not possible on client side.
I'll go for Gitlab API after pushing.